# Asp.net display options only for registered users

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've got application in asp.net mvc with template User Account Authentication. Now I want to display some of options in menu only for registered users. How can I get this effect?

I've tried already:

```
  if (User.IsInRole("ApplicationUser"))
{
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Yours Books", "Books", "Home")</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Search", "Search", "Home")</li>
}
```

and

```
if (User.IsInRole("User"))
```

But it didn't work. I've checked in database and I've found only "Discriminator" = ApplicationUser, no "Role"...

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the `User.IsAuthenticated` property. This is set to true in case the user is authenticated, no matter what role he is in.

Roles can be used to further differentiate between groups of users like Regular users, Pro users, Admins, etc.

Comment: You are welcome :-) . In case it works, please check my post as the answer to close the thread